# How to protect api-key in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, client-side, mlab

I use the [mongolab wrapper](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab-promise) to access the data, but how can this be setup without exposing the api-key.

Is this wrapper only ever usefull for development?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot protect a key inside an AngularJS application. Everything inside this application is sent to the client so easily accessible.

To protect your database, you need a custom API. You can use a service like [Parse](https://parse.com/) to create one easily or develop it yourself with frameworks like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) for Node.js or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for Python.